# Find the number of unique integer solutions to $|a q + b p| \le {N}^{2}$ for $N > 0$ with constraints.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Given integers $|a|, |b| \le N$, $1 \le p \le q \le N$ and $N > 0$ with conditions $|a b| \le N$ and $p q \le N$ find all unique integer solutions to $|a q + b p| \le {N}^{2}$.

I think that the number of cases that do not satisfy the sum $|a q + b p| \le {N}^{2}$ is small, such as $a = N$, $b = 1$, $q = N$, $q = 1$ and similar variations.

For example the solution to $|a b| \le N$ for $a \ge b \ge 1$ is $(1/2) \sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^{N} \tau \left({n}\right) + (1/2) \left[{\sqrt{N}}\right]$ where $\tau \left({n}\right)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Looking for the counts of these cases.

Comment: Anyway, have you tried calculating it for all $N$ up to, say, 10, then looking it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: I have checked with OEIS with no matches.  Non linear curve fit shows a growth of $N^2 \log \left({N}\right)$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Sounds about right. $\sum^N\tau(n)$ is about $N\log N$, so I'd expect something like the square of that. It might be useful to compare the numbers you're getting with the square of $\sum^N\tau(n)$.